# Rest assured : Illegal character in path

Tags: java, testing, rest-assured

I am using response retrieved from one endpoint as path param in another endpoint.

However, when used in URI, it throws java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path.

```
//Post the endpoint
    Response resp2 = RestAssured.given().
            pathParam("id", build).
            log().all().
            when().urlEncodingEnabled(false).post("https://abc/{id}");
```

This is because the value of id used in uri is with double quotes like :-
https://abc/"id".

How can I get rid of these double quotes so as to use the value of id in uri , please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you John and Mohan for your time , I really appreciate it.

I resolved this issue yesterday evening using Stringof function which removed the double quotes and provided me the String like value.

Answer (score 0):

First talk to the developer about this, because the nature of path param (/{id}) is to be replaced by a legitimate value (not enclosed in quotes); something like https://abc/23 or https://abc/param

I would not suggest any work-around for this as this is implemented in a wrong way from REST end point definition. You might go ahead and raise a defect against this.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a shot in the dark here because I feel like the issue could possibly be coming from how you're getting the string from that response. If you're pulling it from a JSON using GSON or similar:

```
String name = myResponseJsonObject.get("member_name")
System.out.Println(name);
```

will print

> "John"

whereas

```
 String name = myResponseJsonObject.get("member_name").getAsString()
 System.out.Println(name);
```

will give you

> John

A small detail but this has tripped me up when using GSON and others when working with JSONs in java.